# Magento 2 : Top Navigation External Link

Tags: magento2, navigation, toplinks

I need to add custom nav link directing to an external site (http://etc)  in my top nav. Admin won't let me do this. Running locally on mac web server.

V 2.0.13 Luma child theme

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps:

go to `root directory\app\design\frontend\namespace\theme\Magento_Theme\layout`

and open `default.xml` file

*Add below code in `default.xml` file before **body** tag end to add  link in **top links***

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="top-links-custom-link"  before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Menu name</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">url</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

*Add below code in `default.xml` file before **body** tag end to add  link in **top menu***

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="catalog-menu-custom-link"  before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Menu name</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">url</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

like this:

> https://www.screencast.com/t/h3qLV5FUw

hope it will help !!

Comment: I gave that a shot but it's still not showing. Flushed my cache. Do I need to do something in my admin too?

Comment: Please send me your `default.xml` file code @guest